# Bash script using sed to replace string with given UNIX system path

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have the following bash script named `SetScript`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# make sure CWD is correct location
if [ ! -f $1 ];
then
    echo "No file at \"$1\" found."
    exit 0
fi

sed -i -r "s/^([\t ]+SCRIPT = \")[^\"]*\";\ #\*/\1$2\";\ #\*/" $1
```

This script is used to change lines like the following in a text file:

```
    SCRIPT = "default.script"; #*
```

The text file is just a config text file that I'm using with the libconfig++ library.

So, for example, if my config text file is named `settings.cfg`, then I might do this

```
SetScript settings.cfg another.script
```

or even this

```
SetScript settings.cfg "another.script"
```

These commands would result in the text-file line from above being changed to:

```
    SCRIPT = "another.script"; #*
```

So far so good.  However, when I try to replace with a UNIX path that includes a forward slash, I get issues with sed.  For example:

```
$ SetScript settings.cfg "/home/me/some.script"
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'
$ SetScript settings.cfg /home/me/some.script
sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'
```

My question, then, is: how can I modify my bash script (while still using `sed`) to permit replacement by any UNIX system path (relative or full)?

Comment: You can change your sed delimiter to be something that wouldn't appear in the file name.   so something like `sed -i -r "s|^([\t ]+SCRIPT = \")[^\"]*\";\ #\*|\1$2\";\ #\*|" $1` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `sed` separator you are using is also `/`, so `sed` command gets confused when it sees so many slashes.

Try setting another separator, for example `_`:

```
sed -i -r "s_^([\t ]+SCRIPT = \")[^\"]*\";\ #\*_\1$2\";\ #\*_" $1
            ^                                  ^            ^
```

#### Example

```
$ echo "he/llo" | sed 's/he/bye/'
byello
$ echo "he/llo" | sed 's/he/llo/bye/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'
$ echo "he/llo" | sed 's_he/llo_bye_'
bye
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you could use arbitrary separators in sed expressions.  But, I would encounter a similar problem after making your suggested modification if a path happened to have an underscore in it.  Right?

Comment: Yes, then you can use for example `|`, which is not url-valid.